# search for common value(patient ID) from column 1 and if all there values in other column (pathologies) is null delete the rows of these common ID's

Tags: python, csv

| PATIENT_ID | PATHOLOGIES |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | null |
| 12 | null |
| 3 | patho1 |
| 3 | null |
| 5 | patho2 |
| 2 | patho1 |
| 12 | null |

If you can see, patient ID 12 is always null
but others can be null or has pathologies
if the same ID is always null, I want to delete it with the related rows in all columns
note: I have 2 million ID, so I want a code to search for the ID's (Python, CSV)

Comment: Please format your question using the markdown editor. It's very difficult to understand what your example looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all patients with only `"null"` variables you can use this example:

```py
import csv
from itertools import groupby


with open("input.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    next(reader)  # skip header

    out = []
    for id_, g in groupby(sorted(reader), lambda k: k[0]):
        g = list(g)
        if all(pathology == "null" for _, pathology in g):
            continue
        out.extend(g)

with open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    writer.writerow(["PATIENT_ID", "PATHOLOGIES"])
    writer.writerows(out)
```

This creates `output.csv`:

| PATIENT_ID | PATHOLOGIES |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | patho1 |
| 3 | null |
| 3 | patho1 |
| 5 | patho2 |